# Math: How to optimize this if so it looks cleaner and faster?

Tags: c++, math

This solution looks ugly. I've tried to simplify using a vector and cycling a vector but would it be faster? I tried making up a formula to retrieve these numbers but I'm terrible at math!

```
if (SkillValue > 115 && SkillValue <= 135)
{
    return 100 / 2;
}
else if (SkillValue > 135 && SkillValue <= 160)
{
    return 100 / 3;
}
else if (SkillValue > 160 && SkillValue <= 190)
{
    return 100 / 4;
}
else if (SkillValue > 190 && SkillValue <= 215)
{
    return 100 / 5;
}
else if (SkillValue > 215 && SkillValue <= 295)
{
    return 100 / 6;
}
else if (SkillValue > 295 && SkillValue <= 315)
{
    return 100 / 9;
}
else if (SkillValue > 315 && SkillValue <= 355)
{
    return 100 / 10;
}
else if (SkillValue > 355 && SkillValue <= 425)
{
    return 100 / 11;
}
else if (SkillValue > 425 && SkillValue < 450)
{
    return 100 / 12;
}

return 100;
}
```

Comment: There is no currently known generalized form for a sequence like the one you provided so it can not be simplified with math alone: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=115%2C+135%2C+160%2C+190%2C+215%2C+295%2C+315%2C+355%2C+425%2C+450%2C+...

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an obvious pattern to write a closed-form solution, so some kind of lookup is pretty much called for. Something like a vector of threshold-return value pairs might be more compact and let you do a binary search instead of linear through the if statements.

Comment: Add an `if (SkillValue <= 115) return 100;` at the beginning, then you can get rid of all the `>` checks in subsequent `if`'s. Also, there is no need for an `else` after a return, either.

Comment: If these values don't have to be exact but are just arbitrary ones you picked, you could try picking new values that follow a math function. I'm assuming this is for a game, most games explicitly use functions to determine skill levels and everything else so that calculations can be done fast and neat rather than needing never ending manual trees like this. I'd recommend recreating how "SkillValue" is determined.

Comment: You could write a lookup table to hold the result - `static uint8_t t[451];`. Your function becomes: `return t[SkillValue]`. If `SkillValue` does not start from zero, your table may be smaller and you could use the offset: `t[SkillValue - offset]`.

Comment: What sort of thing would you consider "looks cleaner and faster"?   One obvious way to simplify the code is to modify things slightly so you only need to test upper bounds of ranges.   You could also store values (and results) in arrays, and use standard algorithms to do the search in a more efficient way.

Comment: Thank you all for your points of view and solutions! I decided to implement the accepted answer's solution. I'm not very experienced so I'm learning about the standard library still!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any pattern to the bounds for each `if` condition, or at least any pattern that would let you write this as a closed form check.

However, you are currently checking all the `if` conditions, which is `O(n)` where `n` is the number of conditions. You can do this in `O(log(n))` by using `std::lower_bound` on a range to find the value of the denominator, like this:

```
std::array bounds { 115, 135, 160, 190, ... };
std::array dens {1, 2, 3, 4, ... , 1};  // extra 1 at the end to account for the 
                                        // case that none of the bounds match
auto it = std::lower_bound(std::begin(bounds), std::end(bounds), SkillValue);
return 100 / dens[std::distance(std::begin(bounds), it)];
```

Comment: But I'm not sure that's correct, because look how the denominator jumps from `6` to `9`. I think you might actually want a pair of lookup tables, or a table of threshold-denominator pairs.

Comment: @NathanPierson Darn, I totally missed that :( Looks like this solution won't work. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @NathanPierson  Ok, I fixed it by adding another array. It's still `logn` this way.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a third argument to `lower_bound`, for that matter? Before I would use this code myself I would need to do some very careful double-checking and reasoning because I find it kinda easy to have off-by-one errors with `lower_bound` or reason incorrectly about what happens when a bound isn't found.

Comment: @NathanPierson Thanks again. Yeah, I agree, this code should be tested before it's used, but then that's true of any code that is found on SO ;)

Comment: Thank you all for teaching me about the standard library. I had no idea about these lower_bound, distance or begin/end. Arrays do seem easier to manipulate data over vectors! I didn't even know a std::array existed since I always declared them on the C style with `type [size] name`! Your solution was exactly what I needed. If you're interested about the implementation, I will share it [here on github](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/pull/4809)

Answer (score 2):

Right off the bat, you are repeating logic in each conditional that can be refactored out of the previous conditionals by switching to the following form:

```
if (SkillValue <= 115) {
    return 100/1;
} else if (SkillValue <= 135) {// the 'else' explicitly means that it is already NOT <= 115, aka IS > 115, so no need to repeat with a '&&'
    return 100/2;
} else if (SkillValue <= 160) {
    return 100/3;
} else if (SkillValue <= 190) {
    return 100/4;
}//... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find an equation to compute your result because your ranges are not equal in size, and the divisor jumps at 295.

To make a more compact version, here's a way:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// 296 repeats to compensate for the jump in your divisor
constexpr int ranges[] = {0, 115, 136, 161, 191, 216, 296, 296, 296, 316, 356, 426, 456};

int compute(int SkillValue) {
    if (SkillValue <= 115 or SkillValue >= 450) {
        return 100;
    }
    auto elt = std::upper_bound(std::begin(ranges), std::end(ranges), SkillValue);
    return  100 / (elt == std::end(ranges) ? 1 : elt - std::begin(ranges));
}
```

This computes the same output as your original function, but I can't actually say I like it any better.

Using a map, it's a little easier to read:

```
#include <map>

const std::map<int,int> ranges {
    {115, 1}, 
    {135, 2},
    {160, 3},
    {190, 4},
    {215, 5},
    {295, 6},
    {315, 9},
    {355, 10},
    {425, 11},
    {450, 12}
};

int compute(int SkillValue) {
    if (SkillValue <= 115 or SkillValue >= 450) return 100;
    auto elt = ranges.upper_bound(SkillValue-1);
    return  100 / (elt == std::end(ranges) ? 1 : elt->second);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and solution! The guys on the accepted answer did something similar to this. I was using a vector instead of a map but was having so many issues with constant iterators since my types of vector were classes. Your simplified version was really helpful! Now I think I can simplify things better without having to find complex solutions to simple problems. Again, Thanks!